# How can I get my cypress custom command to ingest this data (i think i structured the data wrong)?

Tags: logic, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

Alright, as the title says- i'm trying to write a custom command for a cypress test suite. The situation as as follows: I have several tests that need to select an indeterminate number of fields and select an option from the each fields list of drop downs.

The logic for this is crayons-in-mouth simple and works fine:

```
cy.get(selector)
  .select(selection)
  .scrollIntoView()
```

and this works great. But because I use it a lot it's a lot of highly repetitive code so I'm trying to create a custom command where I can just inject an array of arrays (various sets of selectors and selections depending on the situation) into it and it'll do the rest.

This is the custom command as I have it written now.

```
commands.js

Cypress.Commands.add("assignImportFields", (array) => {
  cy.wrap(array).each((selector, selection) => {
    cy.get(selector)
      .select(selection)
      .scrollIntoView()
    cy.log('using ' + selector + ' to select ' + selection)
  })
})
```

I have the data in a seperate file that looks like this:

```
data.js

const importFields = {
  actorListImports : [
    [selectors.lastName, 'Last_Name'],
    [selectors.firstName, 'First_Name'],
    [selectors.phoneNum, 'Phone_Number']
  ]
}

exports.importFields = importFields;
```

and finally, in my test file:

```
tests.js

const {actorListImports} = data.importFields;
cy.assignImportFields(actorListImports)
```

The response I get from this is that the 'select' failed because it requires a dom element. My selectors are fine, so I think it's trying to use an entire array (both selector and selection at once) as the selector instead of the first part of the array.

I know i'm not structuring the data correctly, but i've tried a few different variations of it and my primitive monkey brain just can't put together.

Can someone help me identify what's wrong with how i've structure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to de-structure the array elements in the `.each()` parameter list, like this `cy.wrap(data).each(([selector, selection])`

This is a minimal example:

```js
const selectors = {
  'lastName': 'lastName'
}

const data = [
  [selectors.lastName, 'Last_Name'],
  // [selectors.firstName, 'First_Name'],
  // [selectors.phoneNum, 'Phone_Number']
]

cy.wrap(data).each(([selector, selection]) => {
  console.log(selector, selection)
  expect(selector).to.eq('lastName')                // passing
  expect(selection).to.eq('Last_Name')              // passing
})
```